# Is there a Lua emulator/simulator that supports libraries

Tags: emulator, lua

There are many Lua Simulators out there.  But I am looking to test my Lua scripts for Home Automation for Fibaro HC3.

- Must run on Windows 10
- Must support external libraries, so I can add on the native Fibaro functions
- It's for home, so free or cheap.

OR

A Lua emulator library in PHP or Pascal.  I can then write a program to extend it to add the Fibaro functions.